# Unknown exception during checking out in spree 3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I am getting an exception while trying the checkout after login.

i get the following exception

```
undefined method `show' for ["address", "delivery", "complete"]:Array
```

on the following line in spree/checkout/edit.html

```
  <%= render partial: 'spree/shared/google_checkout.js', locals: { order: @order, step_number: (@order.checkout_steps.show(@order.state) + 1) } %>
```

I know the question is not very clear but any indication where can i start looking ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to call the method `show` on an instance of an `Array`, ruby arrays don't have such method.

I believe you want to get the number of the step corresponding to the current order state then you can try to use the `Array#index` method instead.

Example:

```
@order.checkout_steps.index(@order.state) + 1
```

This will return an index of the `@order.state` in the `@order.checkout_steps` collection (if it is there at all).